# Display a viewpager on popup window

Tags: android, popupwindow

having trouble while displaying an viewpager on popup window.
Wants to display multiple images on a viewpager which is actually a popup window. But unable to remove the side spaces of the window.[image]

Viewpager

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

ImageView

```
<com.utility.TouchImageView
android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Comment: Please upload your layout xml

Comment: are you using popupWindow View or Dialog view.?

Comment: instead of PopupWindow use DialogFragment.

Comment: i was trying this on alert dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this It will remove side spaces and show your dialog as full screen(No side margins)

```
window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Above line is the most important, don't miss to include it.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.DialogAnimation);
dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations =
        R.style.DialogOpenAnimation;

dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_mediagallary);

ImageButton back_arrow = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.back);
viewPagerPhotoSlideShow = (ClickableViewPager) dialog.findViewById(R.id.photolist);
adapterPhotoViewPager = new AdaterViewPagerAllmeidagallary(getActivity(), pagerListItems);
viewPagerPhotoSlideShow.setAdapter(adapterPhotoViewPager);
viewPagerPhotoSlideShow.setCurrentItem(defaultPagerItemPosition);
back_arrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

Window window = dialog.getWindow();
window.setAttributes(lp);
window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Dialog containing viewpager

Either you can set the following style to that dialog as

```
 dialog.setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.DialogStyle);
```

DialogStyle

```
 <style name="DialogStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">100%</item>

</style>
```

Or you can canculate the screen width and pass that to the dialog width as

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
popUpLayout = Globals.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_layout,
        null);
dialog.setContentView(popUpLayout);
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(Desired_Width, Desired_Hight);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: how to use the style? What should I enter in desired width and height?

Comment: You can calculate the screen width and height and can pass that in place of desired_width and desired_height, so dialog will cover the complete width of the screen

Comment: for setting style you can declare the style in values folder and can set it to dialog as dialog.setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.DialogStyle);