# Is there any way to create viewpager inside popup window?

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, android-viewpager, popup

while clicking on the recycler item to show the popup window. Inside the popup window showing **tablayout** and **viewpager**. How to show viewpager inside the popup window?. While setup the viewpager adapter it shows **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090138**

Comment: Yes, you can have a `ViewPager` in a `PopupWindow`. However, that error would seem to indicate that you're using `Fragment`s with your `ViewPager`. Are you? If so, then no, not really. You'd have to do it in a `DialogFragment`.

Comment: please attach your code and xml. It's looks like you searching view in the wrong layout

Comment: Refer this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544829/viewpager-with-fragments-inside-popupwindow-or-dialogfragment-error-no-view

Comment: @MikeM. for DialogFragment can i show case like popupwindow like with in the view position

Comment: Kinda, but you'd have to handle positioning it yourself. It'd probably easier and more reliable to refactor your `ViewPager` and `PagerAdapter` to use plain `View`s instead of `Fragment`s.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for the comments and also find the screenshot where i extactly need https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpfaopl9ynp15h6/Screenshot_20191203-210906~2.png?dl=0

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You do this in this way
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37783900/display-a-viewpager-on-popup-window/37785159#37785159

Comment: @MahabubKarim thanks for the reply i dont need the dialog. I need the popwindow while clicking the recycler item to show

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't look like it would require `Fragment`s for anything in particular. Just redo your setup to use a plain `PagerAdapter` with plain `View`s. There are examples of how to do that on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18710561).

Comment: @MikeM. thanks man! helpful answer. viewpager without fragments working fine..